# Javascript sequential functions

Tags: javascript, closures, sequence

We need to run some javascript functions in sequence. These functions are stored in an array:

```
m = [
  function(){...},
  function(){...},
  ...
  function(){...}
]
```

Beginning with the first function, run it with an initial argument, and check if it returns a Promise. If it does not, wrap it in a promise call and return the promise.

When the promise is resolved, we want it to run the next function, with arguments the result of the previous function.

if one of the functions returns `false`, stop the execution and return `false`

I am kind of new in functional programming, and I believe I am missing a core concept here.

TIA,

Comment: @DanteTheSmith, failed in every try, hence the last paragraph...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```js
let seq = ps => ps.reduce((p, f) => p.then(x => x && f(x)), Promise.resolve(true));

a = [
    x => 'a',
    x => x + 'b',
    x => x + 'c',
];

seq(a).then(console.log.bind(console));

b = [
    x => 'a',
    x => false,
    x => x + 'c',
];

seq(b).then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: How would you pass an initial argument to this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

You must have started to answer this question immediately, and this is why you missed the "initial argument".

@ScottSauyet, I edited the initial question, and probably missed this part :) 

The resulting function (with the initial argument) is

`let seq = (ps, init) => ps.reduce((p, f) => p.then(x => x && f(x)), Promise.resolve(init));`

Comment: This is quite nice with the addition of `init`.  I don't see the point of the false-y test (`x && f(x)`).  Would this simplified version also do?: `let seq = ps => init => ps.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(init))`.  It will only take a single initial parameter, but it's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

A bit rough, but something like the following should work:

```
/**
 * Process array of functions and return a promise which will
 * contain the result of the last function, or false. 
 *  
 * @param  {Array} funcs - Array of functions to be called in sequence
 * @return {bool | mixed} - False, or return of last function
 */
const processFuncs = await (funcs) => {
    if( ! Array.isArray(funcs))
        return Promise.resolve(false);

    try{
        return await funcs.reduce( 
            async (res, f) => await res && f(...res);
        , true);
    }
    catch(err){
       return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
```

This assumes that your build and/or destination supports ES6+ features.

To use, using the OPs original variables, simply call:

```
const result = processFuncs(m); // Will be a promise which resolves to the return of the last function, or false
```

Comment: It will help OP and future visitors if you can share a working snippet as well.

Comment: @krisi maybe you can give some slimmed down examples of the type of functions you would like to try this against (2 or 3), and I can put it together?

Comment: This is very generic, the functions could be mixed, eg they could return an integer, or return a Promise that resolves to an integer or an object, so anything could go

Comment: Using async/await will always ensure that the return is a Promise. From your spec, you didn't need to use the return from any of these functions, just supply the last to the next in the list, and stop if `false` is ever returned. This solution should do that. :)

Comment: I am assuming if you can't use async/await, you are at least using the ES6 native Promise object (i.e. not some 3rd party library, e.g. Bluebird, etc.)?

Comment: How would you pass an initial argument to this?

Comment: @Krisi: I can't think of a way to do this with native Promises -- but that is because these are inherently non-blocking calls. The only other way I can think of possibly doing this is using ES6 `Generators` -- but i'm guessing your project doesn't support those either?

Answer (score 0):

I've just created [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5qLje4z/) as example of the expected behavior: it runs multiple promise in sequential order and stops that sequence when one of those promises returns false (furthermore I coded to return an array with the results of the promises when no promise returns false).
If the function doesn't return a promise, but another function, the latter will be wrapped in a promise which will be resolved with the result of the function.

Here's your array:

```
let yourFunctionArray = [
    function() {
        return function() {
            return "hello"; //The promise resolution.
        };
    }
];
```

Here's a promise which does the work running all the promises.

```
let work = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    let results = [];
    let _break = false;
    for (let array = yourFunctionArray, i = 0, l = array.length, f = array[i]; i < l; i++, f = array[i]) {
        if (_break)
            break;
        let promise = f();
        if (!promise) {
            reject();
            return;
        }
        if (!promise.then)
            promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve(promise());
            });
        await promise.then(async function(result) {
            if (result === false) {
                resolve(false);
                _break = true;
            } else
                results.push(result);
        });
    }
    resolve(results);
});
```

Now you can run that promise:

```
work.then(function(response) {
    alert("completed with " + response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a minor change to the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502358/1243641) from [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg).

It lets you pass multiple arguments to the initial function.  It also skips his false-y test, which I don't quite understand.  Dealing with multiple arguments makes this somewhat more complex than the underlying `let seq = ps => init => ps.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(init))`, so it's not worth using unless multiple arguments are a real possibility.

```js
let seq = ps => (...init) => ps.slice(1).reduce(
  (p, f) => p.then(f), 
  Promise.resolve(ps.length ? ps[0].apply(null, init) : init)
)

// Note that the first function takes multiple arguments

seq([
  (x, y) => x + y,
  x => x + 1,
  x => x * 2
])(3, 2).then(console.log)

// Functions can return Promises or plain values
// A Promise rejection is carried through

const foo = seq([
  x => Promise.resolve(x * 2),
  x => Promise.reject('oops'),
  x => x + 1
])

foo(5).then(console.info, console.error)
```